# What's the word that succeeds dialogue?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What's the next word after dialogue in any given communicative situation?
How do you define a pattern of ordinal succession in words, beginning with monologue, and then dialogue?

Is it polylogue or multilogue?

I thought of multilogue as a better word describing a conversation among three or more people, but is that correct?

Comment: I've never heard a word that's specific for this.

Comment: There are phrases like "group discussion". And specific types of group conversations like "roundtables".

Comment: After monologue and dialogue, it's just people talking.

Comment: There's a movie with only a handful of characters appearing during the entire movie: not one, nor two, but three or more and no crowd in the background. Given such situation, is the entire movie set in a "dialogue" among those characters, or is there a better word for it?

Comment: I think it's just a conversation. That word isn't specific to the number of people.

Comment: I just wanted to sound a bit more stylish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never heard them used, but Oxford Living Dictionaries (I don't have access to the real OED) claims the following exist:

- [trialogue](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/trialogue) A dialogue or meeting between three people or groups.
- [quadrilogue](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quadrilogue) A dialogue or conversation involving four persons.

However, it doesn't seem to continue beyond this. The words [pentalogue](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pentalogue) and [Decalogue](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/decalogue) exist, but they aren't related to conversations. The Decalogue is another name for the Ten Commandments, and pentalogue is a variant of this that means a set of five rules or laws.

And as you can see from the above definitions, *dialogue* itself doesn't specifically mean two people, it means a conversation between two or more people. For instance, many of Plato's Dialogues involve several characters, and a teacher can have a socratic dialogue with a number of students at once. Usually the context makes it clear whether it can be more than two.

Comment: Your example of socratic discourse is convincing. I may be confused about the definitions of prefixes di- and dia- and I have somehow associated the meaning of dialogue with the idea of two. I also have noticed that the word multilogue is used to describe a conversation using social media and forums and questioned myself why it is used only for unspecified large number of people. I was also in search of sophisticated words.

Comment: The prefix "di-" means "two", but "dia-" means "through".